# Given path's format is not supported asp.net for uploading file

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

Here I am trying to upload file from hdd to web server using asp.net

```
string filename  = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName; 
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.ToString() +"upload\\" + filename);
```

Error : An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The given path's format is not supported.

Also this was in output console
"A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Above code works fine on my PC but gives error on laptop.
Thank you for answers.

Comment: Have you looked what is in `Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.ToString() +"upload\\" + filename`? If no, do it. If yes, why don't you tell us what it is?

Comment: From UI, I selected file named "dbinfo.txt" which is present in E Drive.

filename = E:\\dbinfo.txt,                                                                                                       

Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.ToString()= G:\\DROPS\\   and

                                                                                                               
"uplaod" is name of folder inside DROPS folder which stores file in it.

Comment: Based on that comment, you are trying to save to `G:\\DROPS\\upload\\E:\\dbinfo.txt`, which doesn't work for obvious reasons. I will ask the question once again: what is in `Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.ToString() +"upload\\" + filename`. Don't guess, look at what is in there, in that whole thing. Maybe add a line `string saveFilePath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.ToString() +"upload\\" + filename;` and look at that.

Comment: Try `Server.MapPath("~/upload/filename")` instead.

Comment: It seems that in IE variable  **filename**   takes value _E:\\dbinfo.txt_
 and in Chrome it has value _dbinfo.txt_.
Hence path becomes **G:\\DROPS\\upload\\dbinfo.txt** in chrome,which is supported. Still no idea about why such difference in browsers.